# MPAndroidChart: Maintain the same resolution / step on x-axis when on portrait or landscape mode

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

There is a functionality to set maximum number of visible entries with

```
mChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(5);
```

but is there a way to maintain the same resolution or step size when in landscape mode, where the chart becomes longer?

By resolution / step size I mean the physical screen space between x-values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by setting the x-range minimum and maximum according to the chart width, which changes during orientation change.
For example:

```
   final int visibleXRange = pxToDp(mChart.getWidth()) / someMagicNumberFactorOfYourPreference;

   mChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(visibleXRange);
   mChart.setVisibleXRangeMinimum(visibleXRange);
```

...

```
public int pxToDp(int px) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int dp = Math.round(px / (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
    return dp;
}
```